# Percentage of two points line in 2D

Tags: 2d, distance, point

I'm working on a school programming project and need to know a specific point by percentage. For example:

Point1 = 10,5
Point2 = 16,8

Now i need to calculate a new point from the two points and a distance percentage. For example the distance is 25%.

I already did a lot of searching over the internet, but i can't understand how i need to calculate this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

Comment: As another suggestion to get you in the right direction, look up "mid point formula" and generalize from that being 50%.

Answer (score 4):

if you mean the distance is 25% of the distance between them, and the new point is in between:

you can use this:

point1=x1,y1 & point2=x2,y2 & new_point=xn,yn & ratio=r

then:

xn=(1-r)*x1+r*x2

yn=(1-r)*y1+r*y2

Comment: You'll need to swap the last x1 reference in the xn equation with x2. It should be `xn=(1-r)*x1+r*x2`. Thanks for laying this out!